# String interpolation for labelling figures in Matlab

Tags: python, string, matlab, matplotlib

What is the best way to perform string interpolation in Matlab? The `int2str` function doesn't produce fantastic results, but I was hoping to find something similar to the `%s` in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 4
x = np.linspace(-0.4,np.pi,100)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,a*np.sin(x))
plt.title('a=%s'%a)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you simply want the datatype conversion of ascii-coded integers to characters with [**`char`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html):

```
ints = linspace(1,6,6)
strs = char( ints + 'a' - 1)
```

---

```
ints =

     1     2     3     4     5     6


strs =

abcdef
```